# Increased array size. after increaseSize function some arguments of the same array are invalid. C lang

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, realloc

The program takes some txt input from "numbers.txt" file.
It first counts the ***amount*** of all the numbers (freqCount)in that text file, than reads the file again and with the use of malloc it creates two arrays A and B , of which both have size equal to the **amount** of all the numbers in the text file. So far so good.

Now i want to increase the size of the array A, so that I can put "freqCount" more arguments in it. In the freqRepeat function I created, there is a function increaseSize which takes that same array A, and uses realloc to add 2*freqCount more arguments in it.

After calling the mentioned function increaseSize there is a problem, because only part of the arguments remain unchanged, and there are few arguments that become some huge number. This is a major issue. Can anyone please provide me with some help ? thanks

ps. I include the expemplary text file input at the end of the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int read_ints(const char *file_name, int *result);
int *scanFreq(const char *file_name, int *A, int *B, int *resultTab);
int freqRepeat(int *A, int *B, int freqCount);
int *increaseSize(int *A, int freqCount);
void calcmalc(int freqCount);
int *nextArray(int *A, int *B, int freqCount, int freqStart);

int main()
{
  int result = 0;
  int resultTab = 0;
  int freqCount;
  freqCount = read_ints("numbers.txt", &result);
  printf("freqCount is %d", freqCount);
  int *A = (int *)malloc(freqCount * sizeof(int));
  int *B = (int *)malloc(freqCount * sizeof(int));
  scanFreq("numbers.txt", A, B, &resultTab);
  freqRepeat(A, B, freqCount);

}
int read_ints(const char *file_name, int *result)
{
  FILE *file = fopen("numbers.txt", "r");
  int i = 0;
  int n = 0; //row number//

  if (file == NULL)
  {
    printf("unable to open file %s", file_name);
  }

  while (fscanf(file, "%d", &i) == 1)
  {
    n++;
    printf("%d\n ", i);
    *result += i;
    printf("\n we are at row nr. %d sum of this number and all numbers before is: %d\n", n, *result);
  }
  fclose(file);
  return n;
}
int *scanFreq(const char *file_name, int *A, int *B, int *resultTab)
{
  FILE *file = fopen("numbers.txt", "r");
  int i = 0;
  int n = 0; //row number//

  if (file == NULL)
  {
    printf("unable to open file %s", file_name);
  }

  while (fscanf(file, "%d", &i) == 1)
  {
    n++;
    *resultTab += i;
    B[n] = i;
    A[n] = *resultTab;
  }
  fclose(file);
  return 0;
}

int freqRepeat(int *A, int *B, int freqCount)
{
  int lastFrequency;

  lastFrequency = freqCount;
   freqCount = freqCount + freqCount;
  A = increaseSize(A, freqCount);

  printf("\n\nwcis enter\n\n");
  getchar();

  for (int i = 1; i < 15; i++)
  {
    printf("array argument after increasing array size %d \n", A[i]);

    // why some of the arguments have been changed ????????
    }
return 0;
}
int *increaseSize(int *A, int freqCount)
{

  return realloc(A, 2 * sizeof(int));
}


text input:
-14
+15
+9
+19
+18
+14
+14
-18
+15
+4
-18
-20
-2
+17
+16
-7
-3
+5
+1
-5
-11
-1
-6
-20
+1
+1
+4
+18
+5
-20
-10
+18
+5
-4
-5
-18
+9
+6
+1
-19
+13
+10
-22
-11
-14
-17
-10
-1
-13
+6
-17
```

Comment: `realloc(A, 2 * sizeof(int));` - you realloc for only 2 values. You want `2 * freqCount` _more_ values. That's `realloc(A, 3 * freqCount * sizeof(int));` | `for (int i = 1; i < 15; i++)` - array numbering starts at `0`.

Comment: You [should not cast `malloc` in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858).

Comment: @KamilCuk ok, what if i want to expand the array by +freqCount each time, so asuming freqCount=1025, the array A is increased by +1025 each time the function is called ?

Comment: You need to track the current size. If `i want to expand the array by +freqCount` then you need to add freqCount to current size and call `realloc` with the result.  If `int *a = malloc(1025 * sizeof(int))`, and then you want another 1025, you need `int *new_a = realloc(a, 2050 * sizeof(int))`.

Comment: @KamilCuk hmmm, ok... but do You have an idea, how could i automate the whole process. What i mean, is to write a function, that whenever is called it will increase the size fo the array of the same size . Would such function need to include a line of code to find out what the current size of array is ?

Comment: Such function would need to include all the relevant code that are needed to pass along array size. Usually in C you wrap data / objects using structs. `struct intarray_s { int *arr; size_t size; }` and then `int intarray_resize(struct inarray_s *t, ssize_t inc) { void *pnt = realloc(t->arr, t->size + inc); .... }` You need to do it manually.

Answer (score 2):

You unconditionally resize your array to only contain *two* `int` elements. Always. Any access to elements beyond those two will lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You probably meant to do

```
return realloc(A, freqCount * sizeof(int));
```

Comment: well to be honest i was thinking that when i type 2 * sizeof(int) the array size will increase two times.  so what does that line freqCount * sizeof(int) actualy mean ?

Comment: @kenshin Just like `malloc`, the size you pass to [`realloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc) is the size in bytes. The *new* and *full* size.

Comment: Basically. First the value freqCount was 1025 . Than I created array A of size 1025 . I stored 1025 elements in it. Than I wanted to increase the array A by another "freqCount" (1025) so that it has 2050 arguments. Is my logic ok ?

Comment: @kenshin That's good logic, and that's what you do with `freqCount = freqCount + freqCount;`. The problem is that you need to follow through with the actual reallocation (and remember that is can fail, which you need to check for).